# Issue granting permission to domain group via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm attempting to grant permission for sites to AD groups using powershell.  The issue I'm having is that while I see the group in the site permissions page, users in that group are not being granted access.  If I manually add the same group, those users have access.  What I'm seeing is that when I add the group manually, the account name is being converted into a claims token.  When I add via powershell the account remains as domain\groupname.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.domain.com"
$domainGroup = $web.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\GROUPNAME")
$roleDefs = $web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($domainGroup)
$roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefs)
$web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
$web.Update()
```

I've also tried using this with the same result:

```
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment("DOMAIN\GROUPNAME", "GROUPNAME@domain.com", "GROUPNAME", "")
```

This is an SP2013 environment.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below which worked for me.

$ownerGroup = $web.SiteGroups["GROUPNAME"]

which gets the collection of cross-site groups for the site collection.

Instead of using

$domainGroup = $web.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\GROUPNAME")

your role assignment object is fine this way -

$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($domainGroup)